# Permissions on c:\Documents and Settings\All Users

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

What should the permissions be on the "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users" folder on Windows XP? Adobe Acrobat seems to want to write files there but doesn't appear to have the right access. On all systems (domain based) I've checked, I get:

Administrators: full
Everyone: read & execute
Power users: modify
System: full
Domain Users: read and execute

It's the Application Data folder is appears to be trying to write to.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: Actually, the Application Data sub-folder has "Write" access added but the Adobe installer changes this deeper down on it's Settings folder to remove Users and add Everyone with read only access. So suspect it's an Adobe problem - no surprises there!

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft Help & Support article entitled:

[File security issues after converting FAT32 partitions to the NTFS file system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810142)

The default permissions for the "All Users" folder within the "Documents And Settings" folder should be:

> With a manual installation of Windows
>   XP Professional or Windows XP Home
>   Edition, the default permissions of
>   the All Users folder and all the
>   subfolders that have inheritable
>   permissions are as follows:
>
> - **Administrators**: All items (including Full Control) are selected.
> - **Everyone**: Read and Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read are selected.
> - **Power Users**: All items except Full Control are selected.
> - **System**: All items (including Full Control) are selected.
> - **Users**: Read&Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read are selected.